# How do I code better way instead of coding like this VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a dash board in excel but however i would like to know if there is a better way of coding rather than this. I would like to moduleriz it instead of doing this to make it more neat.

```
Private Sub Afford()
    If af.Value = True Then
    af = afr.Value
    Sheet1.Cells(35, "C").Value = Sheet1.Cells(57, "C").Value
    Sheet1.Cells(35, "D").Value = WorksheetFunction.Round((Sheet1.Cells(35, "D").Value * 1.3), 0)
    Sheet1.Cells(35, "E").Value = WorksheetFunction.Round((Sheet1.Cells(35, "E").Value * 1.02), 0)
    Sheet1.Cells(35, "F").Value = WorksheetFunction.Round((Sheet1.Cells(35, "F").Value * 1.9), 0)
    Sheet1.Cells(35, "G").Value = WorksheetFunction.Round((Sheet1.Cells(35, "G").Value * 1.9), 0)
    Sheet1.Cells(35, "H").Value = WorksheetFunction.Round((Sheet1.Cells(35, "H").Value * 1.5), 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, just purely based on this particular piece of code of yours, you could try something along the following lines:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1

    'Input static values
    .Cells(35, "C").Value = .[C57]

    'Prepare for dynamic values
    Set rng = .Range("D35:H35")
    arr = Array(1.3, 1.02, 1.9, 1.9, 1.5)

    'Insert dynamic values
    For x = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        rng.Cells(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(rng.Cells(1).Value * arr(x - 1), 0)
    Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Or, if your concatenated string won't go over 255 characters:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim str As String

With Sheet1

    'Input static values
    .Cells(35, "C").Value = .[C57]

    'Prepare for dynamic values
    str = "{1.3,1.02,1.9,1.9,1.5}"

    'Insert dynamic values
    .Range("D35:H35").Value = .Evaluate("D35:H35*" & str)

End With

End Sub
```