# Multiplying two arrays - Local Decimal Seperator Issue

Tags: excel, vba

***<sub>Background:</sub>***

Just now, I answered a question where I had to multiply two equal sized arrays. However I notice a particular issue with my local decimal seperator.

---

***<sub>Sample Code:</sub>***

```
Sub Sample()

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant, arr4 As Variant

arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3)
arr2 = Array(0.4, 0.3, 0.2)

'Working method for static
arr3 = Evaluate("{1,2,3}*{0.4,0.3,0.2}")

'Failing method for dynamic
arr4 = Evaluate("{" & Join(arr1, ",") & "}*{" & Join(arr2, ",") & "}")

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Issue:</sub>***

Whereas `arr3` would populate correctly, `arr4` would not and will hold a lot of errors. Reason being my local decimal seperator.

Just a simple `Debug.Print arr2(1)` will return `0,4`. Not much of a deal because VBA can still work with the variable that have been inputed with the native (en_us) dot as a decimal seperator.

The issue is that `Debug.Print Join(arr2, ",")` will return: `0,5,0,4,0,3`. And as you can see the dots that VBA would natively need to work with have now all turned into commas. Which in it's turn will not work correctly in a `.Evaluate` that would expect the native dots.

---

***<sub>Question:</sub>***

Any way around this issue without changing `Application.DecimalSeperator` or writing a string value (what I did to overcome this now) which is not exactly great in case of a dynamically retrieved array?

As per request, the linked post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323867/9758194) which basically comes down to adding a few variables to insert a written string of values, eg.: `str = {0.4,0.3,0.2}`

---

<sub>***Edit:***</sub>

Another way I could approach the issue is to use `TEXTJOIN`, which instead of `Join` actually retains the dots:

```
arr4 = Evaluate("{" & Application.TextJoin(",", True, arr1) & "}*{" & Application.TextJoin(",", True, arr2) & "}")
```

The problem is, not everyone will have access to the function. So while this would be exchangable to others with different local settings, they would need to have one of the latest Excel versions.

Another used method is looping through `arr2`, joining each element with `Cstr` however this would also swap the dot for a comma.

Comment: For future visitor's sake, could you possibly post the _work-around_ solution that you identified to this?  I'm sure in the meantime, we can keep trying to figure out how to solve it '_properly_'.

Comment: @Martin, hereby a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323867/9758194) to the specific answer. I will also edit it into the question to prevent any possible future loss of the linked question. But it comes down to a simple string variable.

Comment: In your version on the worksheet how would you write the array to make it work?

Comment: @ScottCraner, i would use `{=INDEX({1;2;3}*{0,4;0,3;0,2},)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that the reason Application.DecimalSeperator does not work in the case of arr4 is because Join() function results in a string, which is not handled as a decimal, therefore the dot is not replaced by a coma.

I assume that code below runs like this:

1. first it converts the decimal sign from "." to ",", including in
   arr2
2. However Join(arr2, ";") results in a **string**
   so Application.DecimalSeparator = "." does not work (reminder - it
   needs to recognize an array item as a number to change the decimal
   separator)

-to fix it, we can use Replace() as a workaround for string.

---

```
Sub Sample()

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant, arr4 As Variant

arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3)
arr2 = Array(0.4, 0.3, 0.2)
Debug.Print arr2(1)
'Failing method for dynamic

arr4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Evaluate("{" & Join(arr1, ";") & "}*{" & Replace(Join(arr2, ";"), Application.DecimalSeparator, ".") & "}"))
Debug.Print Join(arr1, ";")
Debug.Print Join(arr2, ";")

End Sub
```

Comment: Just the `Replace` actually does the job. No need for the `Application.UseSystemSeparators`. I'll wait a little to accept as answer because it's not really what I was looking for, Point being, this isn't exchangable. It works on my local settings, but will fail on any other. Upvoted for now though =)

Comment: I'll get back to it when I come back home from work :P I tried that just as I was leaving, as a general direction of solving the issue.

Comment: A double `Replace` would probably do though to make it exchangable. `Join` with semi-colon, then replace all comma's first to dots, and all semi-colon to comma again....> `arr4 = Evaluate("{" & Replace(Replace(Join(arr1, ";"), ",", "."), ";", ",") & "}*{" & Replace(Replace(Join(arr2, ";"), ",", "."), ";", ",") & "}")`

Comment: I updated the code to see what decimal spearator the user is using on his system and then changing it to "." - will that solve the problem?

Comment: No I really want to avoid messing with the decimal separator. The double replace will do work on any local settings.