# How do i code this better to make it look neater VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to code this better. I am trying to make my codes neater but i just cannot figure how to do it.

```
   Private Sub Test()
    'md = 30

'
'If mbi.Value = False Then
'

'    Sheet1.Cells(14, "C").Value = Sheet1.Cells(36, "t").Value * md * N1.Value
'    Sheet1.Cells(14, "D").Value = Sheet1.Cells(36, "u").Value * md * N1.Value
'    Sheet1.Cells(14, "E").Value = Sheet1.Cells(36, "v").Value * md * N1.Value
'    Sheet1.Cells(14, "F").Value = Sheet1.Cells(36, "w").Value * md * N1.Value
'    Sheet1.Cells(14, "G").Value = Sheet1.Cells(36, "x").Value * md * N1.Value
```

This is what i have tried but i kept on having error

```
Private Sub test() 
md = 30


If Sheet1.mbi.Value = True Then 
With Sheet1
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim x As Long
Set rng = .Range("C14:G14")
Set rng2 = .Range("t36:x36")

For x = 1 To rng.Cells.Count


    rng.Cells(1).Value = (rng2.Cells(1).Value * md * Sheet1.N1.Value)

End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `Next` to begin with, furthermore you never use the `x` variable. Does this refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323867/9758194) answer? Your title is a bit misleading as your current code won't compile in the first place.

Comment: @Jvdv after i used the next it worked dude you solved it

Comment: I still think you need to use the `x` inside your code ;)

Comment: Also What is `mbi`? What are you trying to achieve with `Sheet1.N1.Value`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I was also just wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code won't compile since you got a missing `Next`. To write a neater piece of code it could look like:

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Long, md As Long: md = 30
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range

With Sheet1
    If .mbi.Value = True Then
        Set rng = .Range("C14:G14")
        Set rng2 = .Range("T36:X36")
        For x = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
            rng.Cells(x).Value = (rng2.Cells(x).Value * md * .N1.Value)
        Next x
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

<sub>**Note:** I also edited your `rng.Cells(1).Value = (rng2.Cells(1).Value * md * Sheet1.N1.Value)` since I think you want to actually use the `x` variable.</sub>